# Find corresponding polygon from lat/lon

Tags: php, mysql, spatial

I have a lat/lon and want to find all corresponding polygons (stored as spatial datataype). Using laravel 5 and mysql. I have e.g. a few records with their polygons like:
-United states
-California
-Los Angeles

Now i have a coffee bar in Los Angelas. I want mysql te return the the above records from the database.

What i have now is the following which is returning a error.

```
$results = DB::table('geos')
           ->select(DB::raw('ST_Intersects(GEOMFROMTEXT(POINT(34.051088, -118.249405)), geosPolygon)'))
           ->where('active', '=', 1)
           ->get();
```

The column geosPolygon is the name of the column where i stored the polygon (as     polygon type).

Comment: i think you need need to wrap your point in double quotes to make it `text` like so `GEOMFROMTEXT("POINT(34.051088, -118.249405)")`

Comment: Is the comma correct?